# Initial Value in Vary Command (GMAT)

Tags: orbital-mechanics, astrodynamics, gmat

What number should I give as an initial value in GMAT's Vary command? I have been trying to use default values but in some missions this default value does not lead to the convergence of target or even the optimizer. I have kept Upper limit as 9e300 and Lower Limit as -9e300. By changing the initial value randomly sometimes it converges nd sometimes not? the question is there any specific method which would tell which initial value should be given for a specific mission or how should the value be given or should I continue this hit and trial method?

Answer (score 2):

Your Vary command initial value should be based on what parameter you are varying, and your specific problem. For example, if you are varying inclination for a sunsync orbit, you may need an initial value around 98. If you're varying SMA for a LEO, it may need to be 6678. Take a look at some of the sample missions (in your GMAT folder, `samples` subdirectory).